# How to create JSON from AWS cloudwatch Input Transformer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Goal: I want to trigger notification to slack on any phase change in codebuild.
I have a lambda that does for me and it expects a request as follows:

```
{
"channel":"#XYZ",
"message":"TESTING <project_name> from <build-status> to <current-phase>"
}
```

So I try create a event from cloudwatch events and trigger my lambda:

So I try to use `Input Transformer`

In which the place holders are values of input path from cloudwatch

```
{
    "project_name": "$.detail.project-name",
    "current-phase": "$.detail.current-phase",
    "build-status": "$.detail.build-status",
}
```

But on adding this 
i get the error

> There was an error while saving rule input_transformer_test. Details:
>   InputTemplate for target Id64936775145825 contains placeholder within
>   quotes..

What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 4):

`<project_name>, <build-status>, <current-phase>` needed to be passed as separate values. You cannot use them for string interpolation. [[doc]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchEvents/latest/APIReference/API_InputTransformer.html)

You will need to modify you lambda input format and construct your message inside the lambda function.

```
{
"channel":"#XYZ",
 "project_name": <project_name>,
 "current-phase": <current-phase>,
  "build-status": <build-status>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is json, you dont need to put the values in quotes.

Only string notations needs to be put in quotes.